# libcurl - How to avoid a "new-line" being attached to responses of GET or PUT requests?

Tags: http, post, get, newline, libcurl

A php-script retrieves a string value from a mySQL DB and "echo"s it. - The script is called by a C-program utilising the libcurl api (i.e. curl_easy_perform). Everything works fine, except for the fact that libcurl appears to attach a newline ("\n", hex: '0A') to the string being retrieved, before it delivers that string to the specified call-back function.

Is there a way to avoid this (e.g. with curl_easy_setopt) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libcurl has an API where you tell it exactly what to send and the length of that data. It never appends any newline to that data on its own. If there's a newline too much being sent, that's because you added it to the data and asked libcurl to send it. Or perhaps the receiving code does a wrong assumption or something? The same goes for the responses. libcurl delivers exactly the bytes the server sends back and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will investigate once more - and be back ;-)

Comment: I has been a while, however, I would like to share my findings:
1) Daniel is right - thanks again!
2) the problem was that php-script had a few (empty) extra lines following the php closing tag (i.e.: ?>). Once those extra lines were removed, no extra newlines (as in "\n", hex: '0A') were echo-ed.